# Script to replace characters in file

Tags: python

i'm facing trouble trying to replace characters in a file.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

with open("crypto.txt","r") as arquivo:
    data =  arquivo.read()
for caracter in data:
    if "a" in data:
        data = data.replace("a","c")
    elif "b" in data:
        data = data.replace("b","d")
    elif "c" in data:
        data = data.replace("c","e")
    elif "d" in data:
        data = data.replace("d","f")
    elif "e" in data:
        data = data.replace("e","g")
    elif "f" in data:
        data = data.replace("f","h")
    elif "g" in data:
        data = data.replace("g","i")
    elif "h" in data:
        data = data.replace("h","j")
    elif "i" in data:
        data = data.replace("i","k")
    elif "j" in data:
        data = data.replace("j","l")
    elif "k" in data:
        data = data.replace("k","m")
    elif "l" in data:
        data = data.replace("l","n")
    elif "m" in data:
        data = data.replace("m","o")
    elif "n" in data:
        data = data.replace("n","p")
    elif "o" in data:
        data = data.replace("o","q")
    elif "p" in data:
        data = data.replace("p","r")
    elif "q" in data:
        data = data.replace("q","s")
    elif "r" in data:
        data = data.replace("r","t")
    elif "s" in data:
        data = data.replace("s","u")
    elif "t" in data:
        data = data.replace("t","v")
    elif "u" in data:
        data = data.replace("u","w")
    elif "v" in data:
        data = data.replace("v","x")
    elif "w" in data:
        data = data.replace("w","y")
    elif "x" in data:
        data = data.replace("x","z")
    print data
```

the script reads a txt file called crypto and start to replace the characters based on the statements above. Inside the file is writed the word aloha.

this is the result i get everytime i run the script

```
clohc
elohe
glohg
ilohi
iloji
klojk
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: "replace characters" isn't exactly well defined. What are the exact requirements and what is your expected result for that example above?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement what is more commonly called a Caesar Cipher or rotation cipher

Comment: In any case, you are iterating over **characters** in your file, not strings, so you are printing out one replaced string per character

Answer (score 1):

What about python's   [string translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
import string
with open("crypto.txt","r") as arquivo:
    data =  arquivo.read()
    out = data.translate(string.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw","defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
    print out
```

It is directly equlal to perl `tr` function. It is works as below

Image describes `A` convert to `T`, `C` convert to `G`, `G` convert to `C` and `T` convert to `A`

[image]

> **Then don't get confuse with string translate and string replace**

string replace, replace the whole word. string translate, replace by the each character.